# C# Free IntPtr from C malloc

Tags: c#, c, char, marshalling, intptr

I have an unmanaged DLL on C with func:

```
char* My_Func(char* data, int input_length, int output_length);
```

In this func i have

```
result = (char*)malloc(output_lenght);
strcpy(result,test_char);
return(result);
```

In C# i import it

```
[DllImport(@"libsmev.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr My_Func([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string data, int input_length, out int output_length);
```

And call it

```
IntPtr result = My_Func (n1, n1.Lenght,n2);
```

How to free char* or IntPtr?

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr) and Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(IntPtr) doesn`t work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Release unmanaged memory from managed C# with pointer of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273961/release-unmanaged-memory-from-managed-c-sharp-with-pointer-of-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, something like this:

```
void Free_Obj(char* obj) {
    free(obj);
}
```

In C#, something like this:

```
[DllImport("libsmev.DLL")]
public static extern void Free_Obj(IntPtr obj);
```

And call it:

```
IntPtr result = My_Func (n1, n1.Lenght,n2);
Free_Obj(result);
```

Comment: Free func must be only in DLL where i call malloc?

Comment: @Treno1: It could be in another DLL, but the `malloc` and the `free` should use the same C standard library and share the same heap.

Answer (score 4):

You need to export a function that can free the pointer using `free`. As you have noticed `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` and `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` doesn't work because these functions expect pointer that have allocated using a different allocation function.

If you create an API that allocates memory and returns a pointer to this memory you have to also add a function in the API to free the memory. Otherwise your API will not be available outside the library that was used to allocate the memory (in this case the C standard library).

Answer (score 0):

Instread of creating a custom free function in your DLL, you could also use [CoTaskMemAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `malloc` to allocate the memory.

You can then use `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` to free it.