# Using p/invoke to call a C function that creates an array of structures in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have a function in C that will create an array of structures:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

void GetPoints(Point points[], int* size) {
    size = 5;
    points = (Points*) malloc(sizeof(Point) * size);
    // ... fill in each structure with data
}
```

What is the correct way to call this function from C#, considering the size of `points` is unknown before the function is called?

Comment: That function doesn't make a lot of sense. You're allocating memory and assigning the result to `points`, which, like all pointers in C, is passed by value. That's not returned to the caller. `size` is a pointer, so `sizeof(Point) * size` doesn't even compile (also, this is C, so you're missing a bunch of either `struct` in front of `Point` or a typedef somewhere).

Comment: Also, using `malloc` makes no sense; who is going to `free` the memory. You need to do some research before you start. P/Invoke requires that you follow the rules carefully. I just searched for _"pinvoke return array"_ on the internet and found useful info

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in that code.

#1. If you want to modify the Point array you will need a pointer of a pointer (Or `Point** points`), otherwise when you assign `points = something`, you're just changing the copy.

#2. When you multiply by size, you need to dereference the pointer to, right now you're multiplying by the memory address of the array.

```
void GetPoints(Point** points, int* size) {
  *size = 5;
  *points = (Point*) malloc(sizeof(Point) * (*size));
  ...
}

// Updating thanks to commentEtienne's comment
void FreePoints(Point* points) {
    free(points);
}
```

In the C# side, something like this should work:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Point {
    public int x, y;
}

public class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("YourDllName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void GetPoints(out IntPtr points, out int size);

    [DllImport("YourDllName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void FreePoints(IntPtr points);
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        IntPtr pointsPtr;
        int size;

        NativeMethods.GetPoints(out pointsPtr, out size);

        Point[] points = new Point[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            points[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Point>(IntPtr.Add(pointsPtr, i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Point))));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Point {i}: x={points[i].x}, y={points[i].y}");
        }

        // Free the unmanaged memory
        // Updated thanks to Etienne's comment
        NativeMethods.FreePoints(pointsPtr);
    }
}
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=net-8.0
- https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/passing-structures-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code/
- [C# Free IntPtr from C malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460069/c-sharp-free-intptr-from-c-malloc)

Comment: You shouldn't use `FreeHGlobal` on something allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: If you want to free using `FreeHGlobal` you need to allocate using `LocalAlloc`. The more common thing to do is to use `CoTaskMemAlloc` and pass it back as a normal array..