# Managing unmanaged string across C++ / C# boundary with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have the following struct declared (C++):

```
struct NativeOperationResult {
    const INTEROP_BOOL Success; // INTEROP_BOOL = char
    const char16_t* const ErrorMessage;

    NativeOperationResult(const NativeOperationResult& c);
    /* various constructors, omitted for brevity */
};
```

Now, I have an exported function definition elsewhere:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) NativeOperationResult ReturnFailureWithMessage() {
    return { INTEROP_BOOL_FALSE, "Test" };
}
```

My expectation is to be calling `ReturnFailureWithMessage` (a test method in case you were wondering) from C# via P/Invoke. In the `NativeOperationResult` constructor, it takes a copy of "Test" and puts it in `ErrorMessage`.

The NativeOperationResult has ownership of the `char16_t*` so I need to delete it when the struct is destroyed. That's no problem, but I don't want to delete the memory before the .NET CLR has a chance to copy the string in to the managed heap.

Frankly I'm a bit fuzzy on where to delete that memory. What I think is that the C++ compiler will make a copy of my struct (or just move it) and then the CLR will use that copy... Which means I should delete the native memory from .NET with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your comment. I'm using an ICustomMarshaler for the string on the C# side. And I have already annotated the bool with the U1 type too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, that is not correct.** You need to differentiate between two cases:

1) You didn't do any allocations on C++ side. **This is the case you are talking about right now**.

2) You did do allocations on C++ side, you need to take care of deallocation.

Thus to answer your question: no, your example does not need any "deletion" of memory, since no-one has allocated the memory explictly.

Second case is a bit trickier. If you do memory allocations on C++ side with `new char16_t[blah]`, you need to release the memory with `delete[] nativeOperationResult.ErrorMessage`. This is not possible to do on C# side. The memory can be allocated using different allocators(such as; `malloc`, `new`) and C# does not know how to deal with these pointers.

You need to add a new flag to `NativeOperationResult`, such as `DeletionRequired`, and export new function from unmanaged side:  `FreeNativeOperationResultIfNeeded(..)`. [There is longer discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273961/release-unmanaged-memory-from-managed-c-sharp-with-pointer-of-it).

You can avoid all this non-sense with C++ `strings`. They work magically, and no deletion is required.

```
struct NativeOperationResult {
    const INTEROP_BOOL Success; // INTEROP_BOOL = char
    const string const ErrorMessage;

    NativeOperationResult(const NativeOperationResult& c);
    /* various constructors, omitted for brevity */
};
```

Comment: Note: [`std::u16string` is the `char16_t` version of `std::string`, and `std::u32string` is the `char32_t` version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  Not sure if C# has an equivalent for them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning NativeOperationResult, you can make it an out parameter and expect the calling method to pass it the right amount of memory. That way the .Net can allocate memory and then clean it up after the pinvoke is done. But you will have to figure out a way to inform .Net the amount of memory it is expected to allocate.

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void ReturnFailureWithMessage(NativeOperationResult* result)