# Loading a native unmanaged C++ DLL into a managed C# app causes the DLL to output garbage

Tags: c#, c++, dll, native, unmanaged

I have a native, unmanaged C++ DLL (symulator.dll) which I have to load in and call from a managed C# application.

The DLL utilizes C++ classes and dynamic memory allocation (via the `new` operator).

It exports a function called `Init` and its definition is as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int Init( void )
{
    sym = new CSymulator();
    sym->Init();
    return 0;
}
```

The `CSymulator` class contained within the DLL has a rather simple constructor:

```
CSymulator::CSymulator( void )
{
    memset( mem, 0, sizeof( mem ) );
    memset( &rmr, 0, sizeof( rmr ) );
    md = 0;
    ma = 0;
    tacts = 0;
}
```

The `CSymulator::Init()` method, called by the `Init()` function exported by the DLL, is defined as follows:

```
int CSymulator::Init( void )
{
    int *a = new int;

    *a = 1;

    FILE *f = fopen( "tmp.log", "wb" );
    fprintf( f, "%i", *a );
    fclose( f );

    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

I am loading the native C++ DLL into the managed C# application using this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public IntPtr SimHandle;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

    delegate int SimInit();

    SimInit DLL_Init;

    public void InicjujDLL()
    {
        IntPtr adres;

        adres = GetProcAddress(SimHandle, "Init");
        DLL_Init = (SimInit)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(adres, typeof(SimInit));

        int rc = DLL_Init();
    }

    private void WczytajDLL()
    {
        String fileName = "D:\\prg\\kompilator\\Debug DLL\\symulator.dll";

        SimHandle = LoadLibrary(fileName);
        if (SimHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Blad przy wczytywaniu biblioteki ({0})", errorCode));
        }
        else
        {
            InicjujDLL();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WczytajDLL();
    }
}
```

This code should produce a file named *tmp.log* with the content of `1` in it. But for some reason, *tmp.log* contains garbage data (a random 32-bit integer value instead of 1; for example, `2550276`).

It's not the only function that produces garbage output. Any DLL function that tries to allocate memory dynamically is unable to use it after doing so.

It's as if the native C++ DLL is somehow getting its memory purged by the C# garbage collector.

How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: There's no need to muck about with `LoadLibrary`; `GetProcAddress`. Just read-up on _p-invoke_

Comment: I tried using P-Invoke as well (should have mentioned it in the original question).It causes the exact same result: the classes allocated and initialized by the DLL somehow "forget" the values of their members.

Comment: Unrelated (maybe): how is `mem` declared, and has anything been done with it prior to `memset( mem, 0, sizeof( mem ) );`?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker `mem` is declared as a public member of the class `CSymulator` as follows: `unsigned short mem[ 65535 ];`. So far it is only touched in the constructor; it has not been touched in any other place.

Comment: Interestingly, I also get these access violation errors whenever I run DLL code that tries to access a class. `First-chance exception at 0x571020a7 (msvcr100d.dll) in gui.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in gui.exe`

Comment: Not exactly the same issue, but this SO Q&As may have something useful: [Release unmanaged memory from managed C# with pointer of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273961/release-unmanaged-memory-from-managed-c-sharp-with-pointer-of-it).  In particular, at least one of the answers mentions [`CoTaskMemAlloc` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727(v=vs.85).aspx) as "the" way to manage memory in mixed-mode applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a sec:  Look at the reference below:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate int MultiplyByTen(int numberToMultiply);
```

I didn't notice that your delegate doesn't have the same attribute.

For reference, I don't see anything unusual in how you are doing the LoadLibrary:
[Dynamically Loading a Native Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jonathanswift/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c)

I have done this myself using the exact reference without a problem.  I would suggest removing ALL code temporarily that executes inside the DLL and just do a simple pass-through value. Right now Init() is always returning 0.  Try something else since you have zeroed out memory before, getting a zero back may just be a side-effect of the mem-zero op. Return 1974 or something.

Ensure you have allow unsafe code enabled and use the memory viewer to look at the stack (you are getting a pointer back so you have a starting point).  If you do this beside the IL, you might spot where your memory is getting trashed.

HTH

Comment: The calling convention attribute seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: You are very well sir.